# Scraped data in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I am looking to scrape some elements from various websites that will all return an image and a description. Users of the extension will then select which websites they are interested in and a selection of images and descriptions from those sites will be displayed on their new tab page in masonry format.

The problem is that this data updates frequently, maybe a few times a day with elements appearing and disappearing.

The way I see it I have two options:

1. Scrape the data each time a user opens a new tab via an AJAX request, though I expect this will be incredibly slow.
2. Periodically scrape the data, store it in a mySQL database and fetch it from there.

Are either of these the best option, or is there something else I should consider? Perhaps there's a way to do this in the background so there's no delay when the user opens the new tab?

Do let me know if I've been unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have an asynchronous app that will display the data step by step, when it is available: you bind an object to the UI, when that object is extended/modified then the UI is modified as well in the same time (that's known as double data binding). You could use AngularJS and other big frameworks or little ones like [vue.js](http://vuejs.org/guide/).

I wouldn't bet in mysql in a browser, but on [other forms of storage maybe](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/localforage-offline-storage-improved/).